# Debezium connect: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Ticker

Tags: avro, confluent-schema-registry, debezium

**Problem Description**

I had trouble using Avro serialization on `Debezium` and `Confluent Schema Registry`. I followed the [official documentation](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/2.4/configuration/avro.html) of Debezium. As it is mentioned in the documentation, from version `2.0` the jar files required to be mounted inside the connect container.

Here is the list of the required jar files:

- kafka-connect-avro-converter
- kafka-connect-avro-data
- kafka-avro-serializer
- kafka-schema-serializer
- kafka-schema-registry-client
- common-config
- common-utils

**Workarounds**
For this purpose, I have downloaded all the required jar files and mounted them to the `/kafka/connect/avro_jar_files` directory:

[image: Avro required jar files]

**Debezium version**: 2.4

**Confluent JAR files version**: 7.5.2

Whenever I want to register a new connector (MySQL connector), I face to the following problem:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Ticker
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.<init>(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:181)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.<init>(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:164)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.SchemaRegistryClientFactory.newClient(SchemaRegistryClientFactory.java:36)
        at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.configure(AvroConverter.java:71)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.newConverter(Plugins.java:328)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker.startTask(Worker.java:620)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker.startSourceTask(Worker.java:548)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.startTask(DistributedHerder.java:1833)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.lambda$getTaskStartingCallable$32(DistributedHerder.java:1850)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Ticker
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:476)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:594)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:136)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:527)
```

From the error, I think the `com/google/common/base/Tickercom/google/common/base/Ticker` class is not included in the `kafka-schema-registry-client-7.5.2.jar` file.

I didn't find any link that mentioned the compatible version of jar files for the Debezium 2.4 version.

**docker-compose.yaml**

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: quay.io/debezium/zookeeper:2.4
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
      - 2888:2888
      - 3888:3888

  kafka:
    image: quay.io/debezium/kafka:2.4
    container_name: kafka
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper

  mysql:
    image: quay.io/debezium/example-mysql:2.4
    container_name: mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: debezium
      MYSQL_USER: mysqluser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: mysqlpw

  mysql_cli:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: mysql_cli
    environment:
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: true
    depends_on:
      - mysql

  connect:
    image: quay.io/debezium/connect:2.4
    container_name: connect
    ports:
      - 8083:8083
    environment:
      GROUP_ID: 1
      # Kafka config
      CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: my_connect_configs
      OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: my_connect_offsets
      STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: my_connect_statuses
      BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:9092
      # Avro config
      KEY_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
      VALUE_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema_registry:8081
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema_registry:8081
      KAFKA_CONNECT_PLUGINS_DIR: /kafka/connect
    volumes:
      - ./jar_files:/kafka/connect/avro_jar_files
    depends_on:
      - kafka
      - schema_registry
      - mysql
  
  schema_registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:7.1.10 
    container_name: schema_registry
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL: zookeeper:2181
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema_registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8081
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper

  kafdrop:
    image: obsidiandynamics/kafdrop:4.0.1
    container_name: kafdrop
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKERCONNECT: kafka:9092
        #      - JVM_OPTS="-Xms32M -Xmx64M"
        #   - SERVER_SERVLET_CONTEXTPATH="/"
    depends_on:
      - kafka
```

cURL request:

```bash
curl -i -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" localhost:8083/connectors/ -d '{
  "name":"inventory-connector",
  "config":{
    "connector.class":"io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
    "tasks.max":"1",
    "database.hostname":"mysql",
    "database.port":"3306",
    "database.user":"debezium",
    "database.password":"dbz",
    "database.server.id":"184054",
    "topic.prefix":"dbserver1",
    "database.include.list":"inventory",
    "schema.history.internal.kafka.bootstrap.servers":"kafka:9092",
    "schema.history.internal.kafka.topic":"schemahistory.inventory",
    "key.converter":"io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "value.converter":"io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "key.converter.schema.registry.url":"http://schema_registry:8081",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url":"http://schema_registry:8081"
  }
}'
```

Comment: Problem solved using this strategy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74240305/debezium-2-0-confluent-avroconverter-is-not-working

Comment: @RafaelParaná I fixed the problem and will post the answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with Debezium and its integration with AVRO on version > 2 is that it is dependent to more libraries (JAR files) that are listed on its official documentation.

**Debezium version: 2.5** (January 2024)
Based on [its documentation](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/2.5/configuration/avro.html), it is mentioned that the required JAR files are:

- kafka-connect-avro-converter
- kafka-connect-avro-data
- kafka-avro-serializer
- kafka-schema-serializer
- kafka-schema-registry-client
- common-config
- common-utils

But they aren't sufficient. The problem mentioned in the question is that is has some problem with the Google related libraries (Guava) dependency:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Ticker

I have also checked [the Confluent link](https://www.confluent.io/hub/confluentinc/kafka-connect-avro-converter), but it is still not completed!

After facing to many problem I found that the required JAR files are as below:

- avro
- common-config
- common-utils
- commons-compress
- failureaccess
- guava
- jackson-annotations
- jackson-core
- jackson-databind
- jackson-dataformat-csv
- kafka-avro-serializer
- kafka-connect-avro-converter
- kafka-connect-avro-data
- kafka-schema-registry-client
- kafka-schema-serializer
- kafka-schema-converter
- logredactor
- logredactor-metrics
- minimal-json
- re2j
- slf4j-api
- snakeyaml
- swagger-annotations

P.S. I have created a repository and placed every scripts and Dockerfile that the problem is fixed on that. For more information, checkout [this link](https://github.com/mostafaghadimi/debezium_avro_integration).