# Debezium connect: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/confluent/connect/schema/AbstractDataConfig

Tags: avro, confluent-schema-registry, debezium, debezium-connect

I'm trying to do something similar following the steps in these posts but it doesn't work for me, I'm using bezium 2.5 Final.

- [Debezium 2.0 confluent AvroConverter is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74240305/debezium-2-0-confluent-avroconverter-is-not-working)
- [Debezium connect: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Ticker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77605649/debezium-connect-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-common-base-ticker)

My DockerFile is like this:

```
# # https://packages.confluent.io/maven/io/confluent/

ARG DEBEZIUM_VERSION 
FROM quay.io/debezium/connect:$DEBEZIUM_VERSION
#FROM quay.io/debezium/connect-base:$DEBEZIUM_VERSION

ARG KAFKA_VERSION
RUN echo ${KAFKA_VERSION}



ADD --chown=kafka:kafka --chmod=775 https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/ibm/informix/jdbc/4.50.10/jdbc-4.50.10.jar /kafka/connect/debezium-connector-informix/
ADD --chown=kafka:kafka --chmod=775 https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/ibm/informix/ifx-changestream-client/1.1.3/ifx-changestream-client-1.1.3.jar /kafka/connect/debezium-connector-informix/

ADD --chown=kafka:kafka --chmod=775 https://packages.confluent.io/maven/io/confluent/kafka-connect-avro-converter/${KAFKA_VERSION}/kafka-connect-avro-converter-${KAFKA_VERSION}.jar /kafka/connect/kafka-connect-avro-converter/
ADD --chown=kafka:kafka --chmod=775 https://packages.confluent.io/maven/io/confluent/kafka-connect-avro-data/${KAFKA_VERSION}/kafka-connect-avro-data-${KAFKA_VERSION}.jar /kafka/connect/kafka-connect-avro-data/
ADD --chown=kafka:kafka --chmod=775 https://packages.confluent.io/maven/io/confluent/kafka-avro-serializer/${KAFKA_VERSION}/kafka-avro-serializer-${KAFKA_VERSION}.jar /kafka/connect/kafka-avro-serializer/
ADD --chown=kafka:kafka --chmod=775 https://packages.confluent.io/maven/io/confluent/kafka-schema-serializer/${KAFKA_VERSION}/kafka-schema-serializer-${KAFKA_VERSION}.jar /kafka/connect/kafka-schema-serializer/
ADD --chown=kafka:kafka --chmod=775 https://packages.confluent.io/maven/io/confluent/kafka-schema-registry-client/${KAFKA_VERSION}/kafka-schema-registry-client-${KAFKA_VERSION}.jar /kafka/connect/kafka-schema-registry-client/
ADD --chown=kafka:kafka --chmod=775 https://packages.confluent.io/maven/io/confluent/common-config/${KAFKA_VERSION}/common-config-${KAFKA_VERSION}.jar /kafka/connect/common-config/
ADD --chown=kafka:kafka --chmod=775 https://packages.confluent.io/maven/io/confluent/common-utils/${KAFKA_VERSION}/common-utils-${KAFKA_VERSION}.jar /kafka/connect/common-utils/
ADD --chown=kafka:kafka --chmod=775 https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/avro/avro/1.11.3/avro-1.11.3.jar /kafka/connect/avro/
ADD --chown=kafka:kafka --chmod=775 https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/33.0.0-jre/guava-33.0.0-jre.jar /kafka/connect/guava/
```

My docker-compose is like this:

```
connect:
    image: debezium/connect-ifx:${DEBEZIUM_VERSION}
    container_name: connect
    build:
      context: ./debezium-ifx-init/ifxconnect
      args:
        DEBEZIUM_VERSION: ${DEBEZIUM_VERSION}
        KAFKA_VERSION: ${KAFKA_VERSION}
    ports:
      - 8083:8083
    depends_on:
      - kafka
      - informix
      - schema-registry
    environment:
      GROUP_ID: 1
      # Kafka config
      CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: my_connect_configs
      OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: my_connect_offsets
      STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: my_connect_statuses
      BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:9092
      # Avro config
      KEY_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
      VALUE_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      KAFKA_CONNECT_PLUGINS_DIR: /kafka/connect
      CLASSPATH: /kafka/connect/kafka-connect-avro-converter/*:/kafka/connect/kafka-connect-avro-data/*:/kafka/connect/kafka-avro-serializer/*:/kafka/connect/kafka-schema-serializer/*:/kafka/connect/kafka-schema-registry-client/*:/kafka/connect/common-config/*:/kafka/connect/common-utils/*:/kafka/connect/avro/*:/kafka/connect/guava/*
    volumes:
      - ./data/connect/data:/var/lib/kafka/data
```

But when registering the source connector it gives me this error:

```
{
    "name": "source-testdb-ifx",
    "config": {
        "connector.class" : "io.debezium.connector.informix.InformixConnector",
        "tasks.max" : "1",
        "topic.prefix" : "ifxserver",
        "database.hostname" : "informix",
        "database.port" : "9088",
        "database.user" : "informix",
        "database.password" : "in4mix",
        "database.dbname" : "testdb",
        "schema.history.internal.kafka.bootstrap.servers" : "kafka:9092",
        "schema.history.internal.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.testdb",
        "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
        "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
        "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
        "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081"
    }
}
```

**ERROR || Failed to start task source-testdb-ifx-0 [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/confluent/connect/schema/AbstractDataConfig**

Any idea what it could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it by using the confluent image instead of the debenzium one. I copy the jars to the new image.

```
connect:
    image: confluentinc/cp-server-connect:${KAFKA_VERSION}
    container_name: connect
    ports:
      - 8083:8083
    depends_on:
      - kafka
      - informix
      - schema-registry    
    environment:
        CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'kafka:9092'
        CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: connect
        CONNECT_GROUP_ID: compose-connect-group
        CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-configs
        CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
        CONNECT_OFFSET_FLUSH_INTERVAL_MS: 10000
        CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-offsets
        CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
        CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-status
        CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
        CLASSPATH: /usr/share/java/monitoring-interceptors/monitoring-interceptors-7.2.1.jar
        CONNECT_PRODUCER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringProducerInterceptor"
        CONNECT_CONSUMER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringConsumerInterceptor"
        CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: "/usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components"
        CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: org.apache.kafka.connect=DEBUG,org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest=DEBUG,org.apache.zookeeper=ERROR,org.I0Itec.zkclient=ERROR,org.reflections=ERROR
        CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
        CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
        CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
        CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
        CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
        #CONNECT_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL: "INFO"
        #CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: "org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest=WARN,org.reflections=ERROR"
    volumes:
      - ./data/connect/data:/var/lib/kafka/data
    command: 
      - /bin/bash
      - -c 
      - |
        echo "Installing Connectors"
        confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc:10.7.4

        # JDBC Drivers
        # ------------
        # Informix
        mkdir -p /usr/share/confluent-hub-components/debezium-connector-informix
        cd /usr/share/confluent-hub-components/debezium-connector-informix/
        curl https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/ibm/informix/jdbc/4.50.8/jdbc-4.50.8.jar --compressed --output informix-jdbc-4.50.8.jar

        # changestream
        curl https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/ibm/informix/ifx-changestream-client/1.1.3/ifx-changestream-client-1.1.3.jar --compressed --output ifx-changestream-client-1.1.3.jar

        # Debezium 2.5 informix
        #mkdir -p /usr/share/confluent-hub-components/debezium-connector-informix
        curl https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/debezium/debezium-connector-informix/2.5.0.Final/debezium-connector-informix-2.5.0.Final-plugin.tar.gz | \
        tar xvfz - --strip-components=1 --directory /usr/share/confluent-hub-components/debezium-connector-informix

        # Now launch Kafka Connect
        sleep infinity &
        /etc/confluent/docker/run
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue, and it appeared that I hadn't included enough JAR files. To resolve this:

1. Visit the Confluent page for the connector, for example,
   https://www.confluent.io/hub/confluentinc/kafka-connect-avro-converter.
2. Click on the "Download" button.
3. Once the ZIP file is downloaded, navigate to the "bin" directory.
4. In the "bin" directory, you'll find all the necessary JAR files.

Include these JAR files in your project, and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the Debezium docs is so complete https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/configuration/avro.html#deploying-confluent-schema-registry-with-debezium-containers

It lists 7 JAR files, but I keep getting NoClassDef or ClasssNotFound errors, while I try to use the `debezium/connect` Docker image to consume schema registry in Confluent way.

After quite some effort, I made it working, without having to use Confluent's docker image (that's easier, but a bit too big/overwhelming).

Here is the full list:

1. avro-1.11.3.jar
2. common-config-7.6.0.jar
3. common-utils-7.6.0.jar
4. failureaccess-1.0.1.jar
5. guava-32.0.1-jre.jar
6. kafka-avro-serializer-7.6.0.jar
7. kafka-connect-avro-converter-7.6.0.jar
8. kafka-connect-avro-data-7.6.0.jar
9. kafka-schema-converter-7.6.0.jar
10. kafka-schema-registry-client-7.6.0.jar
11. kafka-schema-serializer-7.6.0.jar

To download those JARs, you can first install the maven tool, then run the following commands:

```bash
mvn dependency:get -DremoteRepositories=https://packages.confluent.io/maven -Dartifact=io.confluent:kafka-connect-avro-converter:7.6.0

mvn dependency:get -DremoteRepositories=https://packages.confluent.io/maven -Dartifact=io.confluent:common-config:7.6.0
```

Then go to `~/.m2/repository` folder and obtain those JARs.

Finally import those JARs in /kafka/connect/debezium-connector-mysql folder and restart the connect folder.

It's not a fun experience. But can be worked out.

I documented the detailed step in
https://github.com/timeplus-io/proton/tree/develop/examples/cdc#avro